# How do i reload the page after the sql statement has been submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following code to try and insert data into my database. The data works fine and i do this using a form. The form has a submit button that i will but the code in bellow the following code. I am using localhost to run my web application.

```
 try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (P_Name, P_Description, P_Price) VALUES ('$_POST[Name]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[Price]' ) ";
   $conn->exec($sql);
   echo "New record created successfully";

 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
   echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
 }

 $conn = null;
 ?>
```

the submit button:

```
<div id="theSubmit">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</div>
```

At the moment when i click submit i get taken to a page display the text New record created successfully. However I would like it to reload the page.

I am aware of the javascript location.reload(); is this what I have to use, if so where?

Comment: Using `$_POST` directly in a query means very simple SQL injection. Since you're using PDO, use its prepared statements. And enable error reporting!

Answer (score 0):

You should reload after execution of your sql like this.

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "New record created successfully";
header("Location: $url"); // tell the client to load $url
exit(); // stop further execution of the current script
```

the `$msg` should be set via session to be able to show the msg after reload.
If you do it like that it is no problem if the user klicks the back button or do a page reload.

After reload do:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

Comment: where do I put this in terms of my code written? Do i put it all in place of the echo ''your..."

Comment: the first part should happen directly after your successful sql execution. The second part wherever you like to output the msg. It is just an example. Of course you have to `session_start()` at the top of your script and define what `$url` should be by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not displaying any DOM Elements, or doing any Header requests prior that PHP Script you can always use the php function

```
header('Location: your-url.com');
exit();
```

to reload a website.

if there are header requests prior that header function this solution wont work so you can add that JS code at the bottom of your script so it gets fired after you have dealt with the form.

Comment: this doesn't really matter. if you fullfill the requirements to run PHP => virtual server then you can do everything localy

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
exit;
```

This will redirect the user to the the same page using a `GET` method, reloading it.